# Laravel Eloquent one-to-one relationship setup

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am setting up a one to one relationship in a laravel application, but I am getting the error "trying to get property of non-object" when I try to reference a related table.

My Contractor.php model:

```
    class Contractor extends Eloquent  {

/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'contractor';

function profile() {
    return $this->hasOne('ContractorProfile');
}
}
```

My ContractorProfile.php model:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class ContractorProfile extends Eloquent  {

/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'contractor_profile';

 public function contractor() {
    return $this->belongsTo('Contractor');
 }
}
```

here is the snippet of my view file

show.blade.php

```
<div>
 <h4>{{ $contractor->profile->tag_line }}</h4></p>
</div>
```

If I just call $contractor->profile the page loads but nothing is echoed back. If I add the ->tag_line,  I get the "trying to get property of non-object" error. tag_line is a column name inside of my contractor_profile table.

Do you see an error that I am making?

TIA

EDIT:  Database info:

```
Schema::create('contractor', function ($table) {

        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('hba_number')->nullable();
        $table->integer('msn')->nullable();
        $table->string('type')->default("");
        $table->string('name')->default("");
        $table->string('address_1')->default("");
        $table->string('address_2')->default("");
        $table->string('city')->default("");
        $table->string('state')->default("");
        $table->string('zip')->default("");
        $table->string('country')->default("");
        $table->string('phone')->default("");
        $table->string('website')->default("");
        $table->integer('company_id')->nullable();
        $table->integer('user_id');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });

Schema::create('contractor_profile', function ($table) {

        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('contractor_id');

        $table->string('tag_line')->default("");
        $table->string('story')->default("");
        $table->string('area_of_operation')->default("");
        $table->text('experience')->default("");
        $table->text('education')->default("");
        $table->text('insurance_verified')->default("");
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant portion of the DB Schema? Really just need to see the IDs that you're using

Comment: Everything seems fine to me. try to debug using `$contractor = Contractor::with('contractorProfile')->find(1)` and in your view try `dd($contractor->profile)` and make sure that property exists.

Comment: I added the $contractor = Contractor...   line to my controller and the dd($contractor->...    to my view and received a fatal exception error.

Comment: Thank you for the help.  There was no matching contractor_id in the ContractorProfile table. Once I added the corresponding the record to the table everything worked great.

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be because you're using a non-standard table name for your `Contractor` model. Try defining the relationship in your `ContractorProfile` model by specifying the second parameter to `belongsTo`:

```
return $this->belongsTo('Contractor', 'contractor_id');
```

You may also need to perform the same mapping on the `Contractor` model as well:

```
return $this->hasOne('ContractorProfile', 'contractor_id');
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, that didn't work either.